# Customizing Highlight Color for dcc.Dropdown in Plotly Dash

Tags: python, css, plotly-dash

I am creating a dashboard with Plotly Dash, and I am facing an issue with styling dcc.Dropdown elements. Currently, when I select an option from the dropdown menu, the menu disappears, and the dropdown button [borders highlight in blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJXTq.png). However, I would like to change this highlighting color to pink. How can I achieve this? Here's the current styling for my dcc.Dropdown elements:

```
.chart-dropdowns {
    background-color: #211F32;
    width: 7.29vw;
    margin: 0.5px;

}

.Select-control {
    background-color: #211F32 !important;
    color: white;
}

.Select-value-label {
    color: white !important;
}

.Select--single .Select-control:focus {
    border-color: #3ad1b8 !important;
}

.Select-menu-outer {
    background-color: #211F32;
    color: white;
}
```

I appreciate any guidance or code examples you can provide. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Add the following CSS to explicitly change the border color of a `dash.dcc.Dropdown` component which has been selected

You can place this CSS, for example, in a file called `custom.css` saved in a directory called "assets" local to your `app.py` file (e.g., "./assets/custom.css").

```css
.Select.has-value.is-clearable.is-searchable.Select--single:focus-visible {
    outline-color: pink;
}
.is-focused:not(.is-open)>.Select-control {
    border-color: hotpink;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 0 3px rgba(0,126,255,.1)
}
```

---

### Demo of pink dropdown border color highlight when "focused"*

****Focus** meaning, in this particular case with the CSS provided above*:

1. When an option from a dropdown component has been selected, or, the dropdown is currently in focus (and thus the cursor blinking → i.e., any keyboard input will be fed to the focused dropdown component)
2. **AND** the dropdown options are not currently being displayed (i.e., when the CSS condition `:not(.is-open)` is true).

For example, the following Dash app:

```py
import dash
from dash import dcc, html, callback
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Br(),
        html.Div(
            [
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    [f"Option #{i}" for i in range(1, 6)],
                    id="dropdown-1",
                    placeholder="Select from dropdown.",
                )
            ],
            style={"margin": "10%"},
        ),
        html.Br(),
        html.H1("No option chosen.", id="text"),
    ],
    style={"textAlign": "center"},
)


@callback(
    Output("text", "children"), [Input("dropdown-1", "value")],
)
def update_dropdown_selection_text(selection):
    if not selection:
        raise PreventUpdate
    return f"Dropdown selection = {selection}."


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

results in this behavior (blue outline border of dropdown, once selected, changed to pink):
[image: GIF video screen recording showing pink dropdown focused border, changed via explicit CSS]

Comment: Hello. Thank you for very instructive answer, I didn't expect a GIF :) It works perfectly.